# Sum string arrays and subarrays in javascript without concatenating them

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I am trying to "sum" the items from one array to another, preserving their children (subarrays):

```
array1 = [         array2 = [         array3 = [
 [                  [                  [
  "A",               "1",               "A",
  "B",               "2",               "B",
  [                  [                  "1",
   "C"      +         "3"      =        "2",
  ]                  ]                  [
 ],                 ],                  "C",
 "D"                "4"                 "3"
]                  ]                    ]
                                       ],
                                       "D",
                                       "4"
                                      ]
```

Edit: Ideally the longest array would be treated as the "main" array (its values ​​would come before the shortest array).
If the arrays have the same number of elements, the first array is the main.

```
["a", ["b", "c"], "d"]
          +
["x", ["v", "w"], "y"]
          =
["a" "x", ["b", "c", "v", "w"], "d", "y"]


["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e", "f"]]]
          +
[["1", ["2"]]]
          =
["a", "b", ["c", "d", "1", ["e", "f", "2"]]]
```

Would it be possible? so far the only suggestions I've found are related to the use of .concat(), however it concatenates one array at the end of the other, and does not merge both:

```
var array1 = [["A", "B", ["C"]], "D"];
var array2 = [["1", "2", ["3"]], "4"];
console.log(array1.concat(array2)) // returns [["A", "B", ["C"]], "D", ["1", "2", ["3"]], "4"]
```

Edit 2:
I've been thinking about the problem in a different way now, and realized that an easy way to visualize it is like this:

```
target = [
 "A",
 "B",
 [
  "C",
  "D",
  [
   "E"
  ],
 "J"
 ]
]
```

I want to add the following element after "E":

```
newelement = [
 [
  [
   "F",
   [
    "G",
    "H",
    "I"
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
```

the result would be:

```
result = [
 "A",
 "B",
 [
  "C",
  "D",
  [
   "E",
   "F",
   [
    "G",
    "H",
    "I"
   ]
  ],
 "J"
 ]
]
```

so that's basically it, merging one array with another.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have the same number of elements? Or can they differ?

Comment: @VLAZ They can differentiate, ideally the longest array would be treated as the "main" array.

Comment: You need to clarify the rules you're using to merge them. For example why '1' goes after 'B' but before 'D' and before 'C'?

Comment: OK, what happens if on the same index one array has an array the other a plain value, e.g., `["a", ["b", "c"]`, "d"]` combined with `["x", "y", "z"]`?

Comment: @Janilson True, I think integers/strings will have priority over arrays, and the longest array has priority over the shortest array.
Priority in this case refers to being added first.

Comment: @VLAZ `["a", ["b", "c"], "d"]` + `["x", "y", "z"]` = `["a", ["b", "c"], "d", "x", "y", "z"]` because there are no matching children in the second array.

Comment: Thanks. So, you only consider "matches" if there is an array in the same index, right? Everything else is merged by taking the values from the main array first and then the secondary array? If so, that clears it up for me.

Comment: It would be helpful to give more examples in your question. Like `["a", ["b", "c"], "d"] + ["x", ["v", "w"], "y"]` Would it be `["a", "d", "x", "y", ["b", "c", "v", "w"]]` or `["a", "d", ["b", "c", "v", "w"], "x", "y"]`? It is a pity that in your only example you didn't go for `["A", "1", "B", 2, ...]` as desired output. That would be "zipping".

Comment: @trincot I added two more examples, it’s a little difficult to keep track when there are more elements, but I hope they’re right.

Comment: @VLAZ Yep, I think that’s exactly it

Comment: Thank you for the examples. The last example seems to deep concat two arrays that are *not* at the same index (index 2 with index 0). What is the logic then to match two subarrays, and when not?

Comment: @trincot I'm thinking of each array as a "layer", so in that example index 2 of the first array is layer "-1", index 0 of the second array is also layer "-1", so both are on the same layer in the result.

Comment: To be honest, the more I think about it, the more difficult and impossible it seems to be xD

Comment: Please note that in your question you wrote *"...in the matching indexes"*, which doesn't seem to be a condition. Can you edit your question? Do any of the answer meet your requirements? If not, could you leave a comment? *"the more difficult and impossible it seems to be"*: I suppose you speak about making a comprehensive, unambiguous specification -- and yes, that can be hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to concat subsections of both arrays that consist only of non-arrays (the number of elements may differ), then merge the next arrays of both recursively, and then apply again the first logic to the next subsections having no arrays... etc.

Here is that idea implemented:

```js
function deepConcat(a, b) {
    if (a.length < b.length) return deepConcat(b, a);
    let i = 0, j = 0, result = [];
    while (true) {
        while (i < a.length && !Array.isArray(a[i])) result.push(a[i++])
        while (j < b.length && !Array.isArray(b[j])) result.push(b[j++])
        if (i >= a.length || j >= b.length) break;
        result.push(deepConcat(a[i++], b[j++]));
    }
    return [...result, ...a.slice(i), ...b.slice(j)];
}

const test = (a, b) => console.log(JSON.stringify(deepConcat(a, b)));

test([["A", "B", ["C"]], "D"], [["1", "2", ["3"]], "4"]);
test(["a", ["b", "c"], "d"], ["x", ["v", "w"], "y"]);
test(["a", "b", ["c", "d", ["e", "f"]]], [["1", ["2"]]]);
test(["A","B",["C","D",["E"],"J"]], [[["F",["G","H","I"]]]]);
```

Comment: Thanks!, I had edited the post with a new example before seeing your solution, and using it as a test I could see that it works almost the way I expected:
`["A","B",["C","D",["F","E",["G","H","I"]],"J"]]`

The only exception is the "F" before the "E", do you have any idea if that was a rule that I mistakenly added?

Comment: The "F" is put as first because in a recursive call the array `["E"]` (1) is shorter than the array `["F",["G","H","I"]]` (2), and so the second array becomes the *main* array (This logic is indeed based on a rule you mentioned).

Comment: Oh right, it makes sense.
Just for the record: to remove the rule about the longest array being the main one, comment out the condition `if (a.length < b.length) return deepConcat(b, a);`.
Thanks again trincot!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
array1 = [
  ["A", "B", ["C"]], "D"
]
array2 = [
  ["1", "2", ["3"]], "4"
]

array3 = [
  ["A", "B", "1", "2", ["C", "3"]], "D", "4"
]

const findFirstNonPrimitiveIndex = arr => arr.findIndex(x => !isPrimitive(x))
const takePrimitives = (arr, pos = 0) => arr.slice(0, findFirstNonPrimitiveIndex(arr))
const isPrimitive = x => typeof x !== "object"

const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const [head1, ...rest1] = arr1
  const [head2, ...rest2] = arr2
  // base case
  if (rest1.length === 0)
    if (isPrimitive(head1)) return [head1, head2];
    else return [merge(head1, head2)]
  // inductive step
  if (isPrimitive(head1)) {
    const cutPoint = findFirstNonPrimitiveIndex(rest1);
    return [
      ...takePrimitives(arr1), 
      ...takePrimitives(arr2), 
      ...merge(rest1.slice(cutPoint), rest2.slice(cutPoint))
    ]
  } else {
    return [merge(head1, head2), ...merge(rest1, rest2)];
  }
}

const result = merge(array1, array2);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for the first example, but not for the others, which is fair since I added them later, I don't know if they were wrong or what could be, thanks anyway!